# Change Text Align After Change Language

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a text area in HTML like this:

```
<textarea name="tx1" style="direction:ltr;"></textarea>
```

Now, I want to change the direction of input text or align of them when the user changes the language to arabic.
Whithout Any Question or Any Button Or Any Submit I Want to know The user language when he is typing. if the user is arabic, set the textarea align to right. if english set it to left.

Comment: you must set this from server side

Comment: For Example, In Facebook Moments When You Type English , Text Align in left and when you press Alt+Shift and Change Language to Arabic, Text Align Change To Right.

Comment: I Can Use Server Side like PHP but i dont know How Or Why use it.

Comment: For Every Thing That input text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the only way i can think is checking the value of text area

```
var arabicPattern = /[\u0600-\u06FF]/;

$('#text').bind('input propertychange', function(ev) {

    var text = ev.target.value;

    if (arabicPattern.test(text)) {
        // arabic;
        $('#text').css('direction', 'rtl')

    }


});
```

But for checking only for arabic is not enought. You must check for every [rtl scripts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left)

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/yhtwbafr/)

Comment: Wow! It Works! Can You Explain Me About The First line (Arabic Pattern) ?

Comment: it checks if the characters are in arabic unicode range. check this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_%28Unicode_block%29

Answer (score 10):

You can do it by CSS only:

```
textarea{
   text-align: start;
   unicode-bidi: plaintext;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yhtwbafr/28/)

This solution works with Chrome and FF but it doesn't work with Microsoft Edge.

Comment: The most practical answer I've found. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not tell us how do you change the language of your user we cannot help. I suppose you will have to use a hypertext preprocessor (like PHP) or duplicate the page in both languages.

In case you do not know anything about what I am telling you, I will adapt it for you to be able to use jQuery instead. However, this is not a good practice if you do not make anything else of the kind of preprocessing.

```
var isArabic = false;
if (isArabic) {
    $("textarea").css("direction", "rtl");
}
```

If you used PHP, you could store the user language inside the session array, and whenever the user changes the language, change the variable, in order to preprocess the HTML so it will show RTL instead.

**Edit**

I have merely understood what you are trying to ask.

Got it:

```
var language;
$('#element').keypress(function() {
    language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
    if (language=="language_code_using_LTR") {
        $(this).css("direction", "rtl");
    }
});
```

Comment: For Example, In Facebook Moments When You Type English , Text Align in left and when you press Alt+Shift and Change Language to Arabic, Text Align Change To Right.

Comment: @AmirParsaKHademi friend so what you first have to do is to do is to say clearly what you are asking. You have to trigger an action when a set of keys are pressed, which is much different from asking "how can i change text direction" which is a thing you should already know. Your question is too open. Re-edit it and be more concrete.

Comment: It is Clear! If You Use Facebook , When You Want to share a moment, if you type english, text align of text area automatically set left, and when you type arabic, automatically set the align of textarea right. i want to do this for my project

Comment: i Should Do This in 2 steps.
1- Recognize when the user change language type. 2- change the text area align.

Comment: @AmirParsaKHademi your question is not at all clear. You have explained it to me now, but I didn't know. In fact, I am not even sure of what you are asking.

Comment: @AmirParsaKHademi so you are telling me you pretend to build a website that due to some odd reason has got a textarea that won't be submitted because you do not know how to build server-side scripts? In case you are just designing it, you need PHP. How can you stand there coding without even wondering why to use a server-side programming language?

Comment: @AmirParsaKHAdemi HOW THE HELL you want to recognise user language? do you wanna ask him? you want to use a button? If you don't tell us we don't know!

Comment: Facebook is using it now. Whithout Any Question or Any Button Or Any Submit I Want to know The user language when he is typing. if the user is arabic, set the textarea align to right. if english set it to left.

Comment: @AmirParsaKHAdemi all right give me a minute. I'll help.

Comment: this will not work, it just checks the language of the browser. @AmirParsaKHademi wants the typing selected language.

Comment: @Giannis you are right. Your answer is better. I'd have voted up if I could.

Comment: @JuanRocamonde i think that's the only way to do this but i am not sure if the browser can access OS's selected language.

Comment: Yes I Agree! Let Me Test it!

Answer (score -1):

On Change of language drop down, if selected value in drop-down says Arabic, the add class to body then writes styles based on that class.

changing all the properties of an elements will lead to performance issue, and not suggestible
cheers.

example as follows:

```
body.direction_rtl textarea
{
direction:ltr;
}
```

"direction_rtl" you are adding class from script

mention all the elements which needs be aligned to right to left

Comment: No no. Look. When You Write a Moment In Facebook, Facebook Recognize your Language Type. If Your Language is english, align of text in textarea automatically set to left. And if your language is arabic ,align of text in textarea automatically set to Right. i want to do this in my own project. thanks.