# How to make textarea lines auto direction line by line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, farsi

I'm having a problem with making textarea lines right-to-left for Persian and Arabic and left-to-right for English or others.

I can make the whole textarea auto direction but what about split lines of the text in textarea?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787351/use-text-align-smartly-if-english-dir-ltr-if-arabic-dir-rtl     Please see the following post . hope it helps you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27658586/8098173 see that.

Answer (score 1):

You could add atribute `dir` to your `textarea` element with value `auto`:

```
<textarea dir="auto"></textarea>
```

Now, browser will automaticaly detect text direction for each line.

Here is an example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/34xs1ykp/)